Find $\int\limits_{2021}^{2022} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{2021}\right) + \arctan\left(\frac{x}{2022}\right)}{x}$ using high school calculus.
$$\int_{2021}^{2022} \frac{\arctan(\frac{x}{2021})+\arctan(\frac{x}{2022})}{x} dx$$
I am sorry if the question lacks context. But I tried to solve it by using the KINGS rule in definite integration. It didnt help with it.
I also tried using following property: $\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)=\arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$ but because of the denominator being $2021$ and $2022$ it increased calculations.

It is preferred that instead of including a picture, you add the problem to the post using MathJax.

Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Also include what do you mean by king's rule , it sounds like nonsense

@jimjim: Maybe this?

yes that what it means :)

see this

FWIW, the numerical solution is $0.0007770449462416128 \approx \frac{\pi}{4043}$, which can be approximated relatively accurately by rounding down the numerator to $2\arctan{1} = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Let $u=\frac{ab}{x}$(this is King's rule for product) with $0<a<b$, then
$$I=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\arctan(\frac{x}{a})+\arctan(\frac{x}{b})}{x}{\rm{d}}x\\
=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\arctan(\frac{a}{u})+\arctan(\frac{b}{u})}{u} {\rm{d}}u\\
=\int_a^b \frac{\arctan(\frac{a}{x})+\arctan(\frac{b}{x})}{x}{\rm{d}}x.\tag{1}
$$
Also we have
$$\arctan x+\arctan\frac1x=\frac{\pi}{2},\quad \forall x>0.\tag{2}$$
Hence, with $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\arctan(\frac{x}{a})+\arctan(\frac{x}{b})}{x}{\rm{d}}x+\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\arctan(\frac{a}{x})+\arctan(\frac{b}{x})}{x}{\rm{d}}x\right)\\=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{{\rm{d}}x}{x}=
\frac{\pi}{2}\ln\frac{b}{a}.$$
Let $a=2021,b=2022$, we can get
$$\int_{2021}^{2022} \frac{\arctan(\frac{x}{2021})+\arctan(\frac{x}{2022})}{x}{\rm{d}}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln\frac{2022}{2021}.$$
